take profit + moving stop when TP is hit
I have been working on a multi TP + Moving stop and now im stuck. when it hits TP the stop moves but doesnt seem to be plotting correctly as it runs after trade is closed, also the intial stop doesnt plot and sometimes doesnt trigger. im very very new to this so any help would be amazing.
//@version=5
strategy('ema moving stop - Long only',
     overlay=true, 
     initial_capital=50, 
     currency=currency.USDT,
     default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, 
     default_qty_value=100,
     commission_type=strategy.commission.percent,
     commission_value=0.05)

// Define input parameters
float initialStopLossPercent = input.float(1.5, title="Initial Stop Loss Percentage")
float takeProfit1Percent = input.float(1, title="Take Profit 1 Percentage")
float takeProfit2Percent = input.float(1.5, title="Take Profit 2 Percentage")
float takeProfit3Percent = input.float(2, title="Take Profit 3 Percentage")
float takeProfit4Percent = input.float(2.5, title="Take Profit 4 Percentage")

// Entry condition for long trades
longCondition = ta.crossover(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))

// Variable to hold the stop loss level and the highest price since the trade was opened
var float stopLossLevel = na

if longCondition
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)
    stopLossLevel := strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - initialStopLossPercent / 100) // Set initial stop loss level

// Calculate take profit levels
tp1 = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + takeProfit1Percent / 100)
tp2 = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + takeProfit2Percent / 100)
tp3 = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + takeProfit3Percent / 100)
tp4 = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + takeProfit4Percent / 100)

// Set take profit and stop loss levels
strategy.exit("TP1", from_entry="long", qty_percent=20, limit=tp1, stop=stopLossLevel)
strategy.exit("TP2", from_entry="long", qty_percent=20, limit=tp2, stop=stopLossLevel)
strategy.exit("TP3", from_entry="long", qty_percent=20, limit=tp3, stop=stopLossLevel)
strategy.exit("TP4", from_entry="long", limit=tp4, stop=stopLossLevel)
strategy.exit("SL", from_entry="long", stop=stopLossLevel)

// Adjust stop loss when take profit is reached
if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    if close >= tp4
        stopLossLevel := tp4
    else if close >= tp3
        stopLossLevel := tp3
    else if close >= tp2
        stopLossLevel := tp2
    else if close >= tp1
        stopLossLevel := tp1

// Store trade direction
var bool islong = na

// Check for open trades and determine the trade direction
if strategy.opentrades > 0
    islong := strategy.position_size > 0
    
// Plot only the relevant take profit levels based on the trade direction
plot(islong ? tp1 : na, color=color.rgb(65, 255, 59), style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2)
plot(islong ? tp2 : na, color=color.rgb(65, 255, 59), style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2)
plot(islong ? tp3 : na, color=color.rgb(65, 255, 59), style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2)
plot(islong ? tp4 : na, color=color.rgb(65, 255, 59), style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2)
plot(islong ? stopLossLevel : na, color=color.rgb(243, 33, 44), style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2)

Ive tried a few things but get same results.
